# Simple expressionengine category filter

Tags: expressionengine, categories

Despite working on EE for about 3 weeks now, believe it or not, this is the first time I've tried to use categories. I basically have an events channel with categories of hotel, restaurant, golf etc. On the events index page sidebar, I'd like to display the categories which when I click reloads the page with only the entries with that particular category.

From reading a few pieces here and there it seems that with path="events/category/{category_url_title}" it should work.

The URL when clicked does look right to me ie: events/category/hotel and the page does reload, but all the events show, even the ones without that category.

Am I missing something silly here? Should the channel categories tag be wrapped in a channel entries tag?

Would appreciate any help you could give. Thanks!

ANSWERED:

Answering my own question here. First off, I hadn't specified the statuses in my channel tag pair (how often is that the problem?!) After that, when I tried with just path="events/category" it worked fine and then I read that there was a setting that had to be turned on in channel global preferences to be able to use the category url title.

So now all is well again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. First off, I hadn't specified the statuses in my channel tag pair (how often is that the problem?!) After that, when I tried with just path="events/category" it worked fine and then I read that there was a setting that had to be turned on in channel global preferences to be able to use the category url title.

So now all is well again!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your problem out the easy way. Head on to:
[GW Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories)

and IT IS FREE! I used it and I love it.

Best Regards.